# find the marginal probabilty density function

Tags: probability-theory

suppose that X and Y are continous random variable with joint pdf given as follows :
f(x,y)= { 15y for x^2 <= y <= x }
find the marginal probabilty density function??
how can i find marginal of y without have any information about x ??

i tried to solve it by drawing the parpolied y=x^2
then x = y^{1/2} 
so x lies between y^{1/2} and y
then the problem become like :

f(x,y)= { 15y  for  y<= x <=y^{1/2} }
then 
marginal of y = \int_f(x,y).dx 
and it's equal 15(y^{3\2} - y )
is thats right ?????!!

Comment: The (marginal) density of $y$ is $0$ outside the interval $[0,1]$. In the interval $[0,1]$, it is $15(y^{3/2}-y^2)$. (You had a little calculation slip, or typo).

Comment: You are welcome. In such problems, drawing the region in which the joint density function "lives" can be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

For what values is $x^2<x$? That's right, for $0 <x <1$, these are your bounds. Now integrate to make sure this is right:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x^2}^{x} 15 y dy dx=1
$$
Now use this solution to get the marginals.

Comment: so x lies in the interval [0,1] ??

Comment: yes, because $x^2<x$